# Typo3 Fatal error: Error\Exception: PHP Warning: gzuncompress()

Tags: docker, typo3, ddev

I have updated my Typo3 ddev installation and i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception: PHP Warning: gzuncompress(): data error in /var/www/html/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/Backend/Typo3DatabaseBackend.php line 158 in /var/www/html/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Error/ErrorHandler.php:130 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'gzuncompress():...', '/var/www/html/p...', 158, Array) #1 /var/www/html/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/Backend/Typo3DatabaseBackend.php(158): gzuncompress('a:1:{i:0;a:25:{...') #2 /var/www/html/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/Frontend/VariableFrontend.php(81): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Backend\Typo3DatabaseBackend->get('1__0_-99') #3 /var/www/html/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/RootlineUtility.php(211): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Frontend\VariableFrontend->get('1__0_-99') #4 /var/www/html/public/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Configuration/BackendConfigurationManager.php(68): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\RootlineUtility->get() #5 /var/www/html/public/typo3/sysext/ex in /var/www/html/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Error/ErrorHandler.php on line 130
```

I don't understand what i'm missing.
I have did composer update, didn't solve it.
Even installtool say "no site configuration" "page are inaccessible"
Typo3 10.4
PHP 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find the solution, i was had a bad cache configuration in the localconf file, so i deleted all backend cache configuration:

```
[
        'cacheConfigurations' => [
            'hash' => [
                'backend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\Typo3DatabaseBackend',
            ],
            'imagesizes' => [
                'backend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\Typo3DatabaseBackend',
                'options' => [
                    'compression' => 1,
                ],
            ],
            'pages' => [
                'backend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\Typo3DatabaseBackend',
                'options' => [
                    'compression' => 1,
                ],
            ],
            'pagesection' => [
                'backend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\Typo3DatabaseBackend',
                'options' => [
                    'compression' => 1,
                ],
            ],
            'rootline' => [
                'backend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\Typo3DatabaseBackend',
                'options' => [
                    'compression' => 1,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

So i guess that the caching method that i was using it wasn't working... maybe from my server side, i hope i find a solution for caching.

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar problem and truncating all cache tables on the database solved it for me.

Comment: For future readers: This can be done from the command line with `typo3 cache:flush` or (if you have the alternative extension "typo3cms" installed): `typo3cms cache:flush`. This way I didn't need a browser and I didn't need low-level SQL access. There was an error about missing permissions (or similar) but the cache tables _were_ flushed/truncated, and after a page reload I was able to login into the TYPO3 backend.

Answer (score 2):

This may happen if you have utf8mb4 configured in TYPO3 configuration for the database but it is an old database with utf8 encoding.

Solution:

1. Dump the database
2. Drop the database
3. Create the database
4. Import the dump

You may want to check the dump that it does not force old utf8 encoding.

Comment: I did that but this didn't help, the issue still there.